# Cucumber @Before questions

Tags: cucumber

Okay so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but i have my project setup like this:

Top level package/
   Feature package that contains one feature file/
   Page package that contains one page class/
   Steps package that contains one step page./
   Utils package that contains runner class and a "hook" class + a class that just contains a web driver that gets passed around.

in the Hook class i have method annotated with @Before. Now if i go into the feature file right click on a scenario and run it, the method in the hook class gets called np and everything is well.

If i go into my runner class and run the test from there, the method doesn't get called and the step methods in the Step class are being called first.

If i put a @Before method in the Step class this works fine, but i don't wanna duplicate my code, how do i work around this?

Edit: sorry i'm not sure why my indentation looks horrible.

Comment: Does the value you are giving to the 'glue' option to the runner class include the classpath of the hook class which has your before method... Ideally you should move the hook into the same package structure with the step definition classes...

Comment: That was it, in the glue i was only specifying the path to the steps package, and i wasn't pointing to the hook one as well. Thanks!